# IHttpContextAccessor is null in one repository

Tags: .net, entity-framework, dependency-injection, .net-7.0

--dotnet7-- I am trying to get my user id from the token in the header with the **HttpContextAcessor**, I registered my repositories and the HttpContextAcessor in the Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IWardrobeService, WardobreService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IGuildService, GuildService>();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Inside the **WardrobeService**, i can use the accessor and it returns the id. 
WardrobeService.cs:

```
private readonly DataContext _context;
private readonly IMapper _mapper;
private readonly IEffectService _fxService;
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContext;
private readonly IDMService _dmService;
public WardobreService(DataContext context, IMapper mapper, IEffectService fxService, IHttpContextAccessor httpContext, IDMService dmService)
{   
    _context = context;
    _mapper = mapper;
    _fxService = fxService;
    _httpContext = httpContext;
    _dmService = dmService;
}
// Needed Methods
private int GetCurrentUserId() => int.Parse(
    _httpContext.HttpContext!.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)!
);
```

But if i try this in the **GuildService**, the accessor always returns null. 
GuildService.cs:

```
private readonly IMapper _mapper;
private readonly DataContext _context;
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContext;
private readonly IWardrobeService _wardrobe;
public GuildService(IMapper mapper, DataContext context, IHttpContextAccessor httpContext, IWardrobeService wardrobe)
{
    _context = context;
    _mapper = mapper;
    _httpContext = httpContext;
    _wardrobe = wardrobe;
}
// Needed Methods
private int GetCurrentUserId() => int.Parse(
    _httpContext.HttpContext!.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)!
);
private async Task<Character> GetCurrentCharacter()
{
    var c = await _context.Characters.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.UserId == GetCurrentUserId());
    return c!;
}
```

Here when i try to use **GetCurrentCharacter()**, i get a error because **GetCurrentUserId()** returns null.
As far as i can understand, i did the same thing in both repositories and i can't figure why the **_httpContext.HttpContext** always returns **null**.

I tried rewriting the **GuildService**, didn't work.  I tried calling **_wadrobeService** inside **GuildService**; if i do this, then the problem happens inside **WardrobeService** 
**Udpate**: 
The problem was solved by adding [Authorize] on the controller that was calling the **GuildService**. That was the difference between the two repositories, one was being called on a controller with [Authorize] and the other was not.

Comment: Where are you calling `GetCurrentCharacter` from?

Comment: Please show code calling `GuildService` and please add the class declaration for `GuildService` (i.e. `public class ....`). P.S. _" I registered my repositories "_ - I would argue that injecting `IHttpContextAccessor` into repository is a huge code smell, though (also it is up for debate if the show services are repositories).

Comment: Is this code running in the context of a web request, or is this running on a background thread. Running on a background thread can happen, for instance, when you started an asynchronous operation that you *didn't `await` on*.

Comment: @GuruStron Why is injecting IHttpContextAccessor a code smell, and do you have any suggestions of places to read about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a lot of #null forgiving going on in there. Break it down and inspect.

```
private int GetCurrentUserId() 
{
    var user = _httpContext.HttpContext?.User;
    if(user == null) 
        throw new ApplicationException("No user session");

    var name = user.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        throw new ApplicationException("No user name claim.");

    var result = int.TryParse(name, out int userId)
    if (!result)
        throw new ApplicationException("User name claim not a User ID.");

    return userId;
}
```

In all cases where a user session state isn't retrievable, the entire session should be dumped, forcing the user to re-authenticate. Breaking it up to see what's actually set (or not) should help narrow down the problem.

Areas to check wound be looking at the call stack for where/when this specific repository is being called in the overall request. If it's somehow being called while not in the scope of an Http Request then the Context Accessor may not resolve a current session. Where is this GuildService being injected/resolved, and how does that differ from the other services that appear to work?

Comment: I did like you said and checked where my class was being called, the controller, and it turns out i forgot to add [Authorize], it solved the problem. Thanks, i didnt upvote because i dont have enough reputation.